# wiring a bedside lamp

Tags: wiring

I have a light socket that I was going to replace and the new socket has 3 terminals but I only have 2 wires (typical lamp cord) coming to the socket. How should I hook up the wires

Comment: Does one of the terminals have a green screw (ground)?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Post a picture of the new socket ..